# How to correctly set permission for a localhost server in Fedora using Laravel?

Tags: apache, localhost, fedora

I am attempting to run a laravel app on a local server in https mode  in a Fedora 36 OS, but I am given this message

> The stream or file "/var/www/compagnon-be/storage/logs/laravel.log"
> could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream:  Permission
> denied The exception occurred while attempting to log

It seems to me that my permissions are correct

My DocumentRoot is /var/www/compagnon-be/public

I used these commands from /var/www

```
sudo chown -R $USER:apache compagnon-be
```

and

```
sudo chmod -R 775 compagnon-be
```

ls -l returns this (muser being my user)

```
[jaaf@localhost www]$ ls -l
total 12
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   4096 17 juin  13:13 cgi-bin
drwxrwxr-x. 14 muser apache 4096  2 déc.  06:32 compagnon-be
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root   4096  1 déc.  06:52 html
[jaaf@localhost www]$
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The trouble was coming from selinux.
I tried

```
sudo restorecon -R -v  /var/www/compagnon-be
```

After that the message changed to

> file_put_contents(/var/www/compagnon-be/storage/framework/views/dc2fe5ffc0c4db448244e2a441f79c65b3812ff5.php):
> Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Then I decided to install setroubleshoot package in my Fedora distribution and launched sealert

Refreshing the page triggered an alert and sealert gave me the commands to use
It was:
Vous devez modifier l'étiquette sur (You must change label on) « /var/www/compagnon-be/storage/framework/views »

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/compagnon-be/storage/framework/views'

# restorecon -v '/var/www/compagnon-be/storage/framework/views'
```